# How to filter null values from a list to pass it to Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, filter, null

So I have a list that cointains null values. i need to sort that list without the nulls.

so thats what i have:

```
 foreignList.stream().filter(c -> c.getForeignBureauInquiryDocSlot() != null);
 Collections.sort(foreignList, ((DocumentSorting o1, DocumentSorting o2) -> o1.getForeignBureauInquiryDocSlot() - o2.getForeignBureauInquiryDocSlot()));
```

but it returns nullPointerException

Comment: What is the object type inside list?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach helps you.

```
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
Collections.sort(list);
```